# append a child in javascript in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first program to make an extension in Google chrome, i just took the "hello world" tutorial as example from [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)

This is my html file source code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
  <style>
    body {
      min-width:357px;
      overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    img {
      margin:5px;
      border:2px solid black;
      vertical-align:middle;
      width:75px;
      height:75px;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

ad this is my javascript file source code :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" +
    "method=flickr.photos.search&" +
    "api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&" +
    "text=hello%20world&" +
    "safe_search=1&" +  // 1 is "safe"
    "content_type=1&" +  // 1 is "photos only"
    "sort=relevance&" +  // another good one is "interestingness-desc"
    "per_page=20",
true);
req.onload = showPhotos;
req.send(null);

function showPhotos() {
   var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");

   var element = document.createElement('h1');
   element.appendChild(document.createTextNode 
   ('tete '+document.location.href+'hgdfhgd'));

   for (var i = 0, photo; photo = photos[i]; i++) {
   var img = document.createElement("image");
   img.src = constructImageURL(photo);
   document.body.appendChild(img);
 }
}

// See: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html
function constructImageURL(photo) {
   return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
  ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
  "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
  "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
  "_s.jpg";
}
```

The example is very simple and it works fine, but when add my own javascript instruction, it doesn't display it, the instruction that added is in showPhotos() function and it's :

```
   var element = document.createElement('h1');
   element.appendChild(document.createTextNode 
   ('tete '+document.location.href+'hgdfhgd'));
```

in the result, i can see the other content but my 'h1' i don't see it.
i missed something ? can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an element but you're not adding it to the page. So it can't be visible.

You can see it you add it, for example like this :

```
var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode ('tete '+document.location.href+'hgdfhgd'));
document.body.appendChild(element);
```